# How do I update LTspice IV for macOS?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

On an iMac and a Macbook, both running macOS Sierra 10.12.6, I have installed the latest LTspice IV (Build Oct 3 2016, 14:49:11 US Pacific), which prompts me to update on launch. Attempting to do so via either the **Model Update** or **Software Update** buttons in the Operation tab causes the spinning wheel for about 10 minutes before finally crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`.

On Windows I had similar issues when behind a proxy, but there are no such Internet shenanigans here.

Does anyone know a way to update LTspice IV on macOS? I'm happy to do it manually via `~/Library/Application Support/LTspice` if necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an EE question.

Comment: I was concerned about that but saw lots of other q's about using LTSpice (rather than about EE specifically) and LTSpice is a popular tag. Looks like I've copped some reputation on this punt. Happy to close if it's off-topic, but pretty hard to determine that up front.

Comment: I don't agree an LTspice question is off-topic. Why don't we leave it open just in case another Mac user comes along who managed to solve this?

Comment: same problem here - LTSpice says it's 433 days old and wont update itself, hanging, crashing etc. also the Mac version doesn't know about ADxxx components. the PC version does though. Why such discrepancy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**LTSpice for macOS** has finally been **updated to LTspice XVII as of October 25th, 2018**.  I have verified that it has resolved the model update bug, as well as most other noticeable issues that had cropped up in the last release.

So the updated answer to this question is to simply download the latest version - it fixes the model update crash and many other issues as well.  Even the icons have been tweaked.

The new URL (since Linear Technology has since become part of Analog Devices) to download the latest LTSpice version (I would be surprised if the self-update function worked, given the change) **[is here](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html)**.

Comment: Bummer. LTSpice XVII crashes regularly. Simulating, picking a diode, picking a MOSFET, plotting. Crash, crash, crash. Proceed with caution!

Comment: The Feb  7 2019 build fixes the vast majority of these crashing bugs. We're back in the game!

Comment: I used this link and it is not working for me I have version 10.15.3.

Answer (score 3):

I also was stuck on this and decided to trace it down. So what the `Software Update` does is to download a file named `LTspiceAppUpdater` which is put in `/Applications/LTspice.app/Contents/`. This waits for `LTspice` to terminate itself. It then simply downloads the most recent `LTspice.dmg` from Linear.com in the same location and extracts the files. So basically it replaced your recent installation with the same copy. Then on restarting it just hangs in an infinite loop. I could not figure out where exactly the version is checked, but since I deleted each and every trace of `LTspice` and it still croaks it's most likely that they just look into some token in the program code itself.

**tl;dr** It's a bug in the implementation and you can only get rid of it by reporting it to Linear.com. Though I think it's unlikely they will fix it in the near future - if ever. Just click away the message at start and have a look for a new version next year.

There's a new version available, but that crashes permanently (not only with my installation). Here's a link to the old version: https://www.heise.de/download/product/lt-spice-iv-65702/download (it's a German magazine and it should be safe to download in any case)
Or even better: use the link in @HiromichiMatsushima's answer. This seems to be a much more stable release.

Comment: I think this is the closest we're going to come to an answer - your answer suggests that software update is broken, but it doesn't matter anyway because there is nothing to update to. Accepted.

Comment: Yes, annoying. But that's the case with so many software. Don't make it frustrate you. Contemplate ;-)

Comment: This was the correct answer at the time, but there's now a more correct answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/404957/94854 I don't want to de-crown this effort though.

Comment: @HeathRaftery Thanks. I use LTSpice only eventually and for sure would not have noticed that update since I gave up (like most OS X users I guess ;-). I'll add a link to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that you are the OP. Just take the check mark back and assign it to the new one. I don't mind about the points here. I got enough at SO ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The build date/time is hard coded in the executable.  Open LTSpice executable in a hex editor and goto offset 0x49FA4A and change 0x36 to 0x38.  Now it will think the build time is October 2018 and it won't popup that annoying message anymore.

LTspice MD5 = e7a2de8bb82e2419e981ed425c359626

Comment: Wow this works! How did you know?

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp of "LTspice for Mac OS X" in [download page](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) is not updated, but you can download recent (updated) installer from download link in the page.

I succeeded in updating with this installer.

Comment: Confirmed! Both the **Model Update** and **Software Update** buttons seem to work.

Comment: Confirmed as well.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would try:

1) Download the new LTSPICE IIXV (or whatever number it is) and see if that works any better

2) Un install and reinstall LT SPICE

3) find an updated copy on a different machine and move over the lib and examples folders

Comment: 1) Not available for Mac. 2) Several times 3) Can't update on any machine. Fresh install does not update.

Comment: Find a friend that has a PC, if its all your machines including the PC's check your firewall

Comment: No firewall. Plenty of PCs. They work. What do you suggest to do with them to solve the issue? There is no examples folder, for example.

Comment: Please see idea #3 above

Comment: latest LTSpice for Mac on LT website is dated October 2016. Anyone know where to get a newer version? It's not showing on LT website.

Answer (score 1):

I like rxprobe's hack, but cannot try since I got so tired of the message and figured it was never going to be resolved by LTC that I moved to LTSpice XVII. This one isn't available for macOS, but installing Wine via Homebrew and then installing this updated Windows executable works just as well. Runs just as fast and appears to be stable; updates correctly as well.