# LTSpice IV for OS X (oct 2, 2018 version) crashes on macOS Mojave 10.14

Tags: simulation, ltspice, osx

I downloaded the latest LTSpice IV for mac OS, I'm running mojave on a MBP. 
It is crashing in my setup, apparently as soon as it opens the plot window. The simulation starts running, but when it's ready to plot and opens the plot window, crashes.

EDIT >>>
This happens regardless of the model simulated, existing or new, even a simple AC source makes it crash.

Is anyone else experimenting this issue?

The error report says (I paste what I think is relevant):

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00006884fbd14fb8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [61028]

VM Regions Near 0x6884fbd14fb8:
    MALLOC_NANO (reserved) 0000600008000000-0000600020000000 [384.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  reserved VM address space (unallocated)
--> 
    STACK GUARD            00007000012bf000-00007000012c0000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 6

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: initWithFocusedViewRect:


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff60437a1d objc_msgSend + 29
1   LTC.LTspice                     0x0000000107493328 -[RAWview drawRect:] + 4517
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff31b01205 _NSViewDrawRect + 66
```

PS: Yes, finally Analog has released an LTSpice IV version for mac. The download page says 2016 but actually it's a release from 2018. See this question. [How do I update LTspice IV for macOS?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323430/how-do-i-update-ltspice-iv-for-macos) 
Among other things it fixes the "xx days old, please update" problem.

Comment: Looks like something to let Mike know (the creator of the program), it might be a legit bug. On Windows, the email address to send to is in `Help > About`, maybe it's the same on MacOS. Be sure to make the email short and concise, don't use too many words where a few can do it -- he's known for his temper, which is partly justified.

Comment: Please make your title and body consistent, crashed and hangs are two different situations.  Also specify if this happens regardless of design, or else document the deck being simulated when this occurred..

Comment: Thanks, I'll send email from Help. Also edited title to reflect it crashes and text to specify that it happens regardless of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and I emailed Mike yesterday and he replied saying there are many problem with Mojave and he fixed the major bug about macOS mojave. I updated my LTspice and it is working fine now. Maybe you want to try to update using "operations" and choose "software update". Hope that will solve your problem.