# Best place to report an LTSpice XVII crasher?

Tags: ltspice, osx

I have a small LTspice XV11 .asc file that reliably gives a SIGSEGV when I run the simulator under macOS 10.14.3 (Mojave).

This is related to [LTSpice IV for OS X (oct 2, 2018 version) crashes on macOS Mojave 10.14](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400648/ltspice-iv-for-os-x-oct-2-2018-version-crashes-on-macos-mojave-10-14), except:

- I have updated to the "Feb  7 2019, 11:03:59 US Pacific" release
- The email address for Mike Engelhardt is no longer listed in the about box of LTspice (at least, not on the macOS version)

At the risk of asking two questions in one post, here's a link to the .asc file in case anyone wants to replicate the bug:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JCn2yEk1XB7FvNAyWjqBhhO60fnvhZno/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The circuit works fine on Windows LTspiceXVII. The e-mail to report bugs is LTspice@analog.com Get some real OS.

Comment: It also works on Archlinux x64 with Wine. I wouldn't say it's the OS, but the LTspice Mac builds are not regarded as very stable, at least not from the many complaints I've seen. You're better off using Wine, too. At least, for now.

Comment: @Ale..chenski: Okay, I'll run it under Linux.  :)  (In all seriousness, thank you for verifying LTspice works under Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

As [Ale..chenski](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/117785/ale-chenski) points out, even though Mike Engelhardt's email address is no longer listed in the LTspice about box, you can use the address

```
LTspice@analog.com
```

for support questions.

Comment: That is still his address, just on a different domain since the acquisition of LT by ADI.